# Capybara is not missing constant RackTest! (ArgumentError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, cucumber, capybara

I'm very confused by this error I'm getting. If Capybara is NOT missing the constant, why is it complaining???

**Background**

I am upgrading a Rails app and am now running on Rails 3.0.7 and Ruby 1.9.3. I upgraded to Cucumber 1.1.2 and after some picky work and running around in circles, all of my tests were running fine. I then tried to upgrade Rspec to get those tests running. Again, with some running around in circles I managed to get the Rspec tests running with 'rspec-rails' 3.2.0 and Capybara 2.2.0.

Yay me!

But then I went back to the Cucumber tests to check something, and...*BAM*. Cucumber tests are broken with a very strange error message...

```
Capybara is not missing constant RackTest! (ArgumentError)
/Users/camillavk/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@rails3/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:479:in `load_missing_constant'
/Users/camillavk/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@rails3/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:183:in `block in const_missing'
/Users/camillavk/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@rails3/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:181:in `each'
/Users/camillavk/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@rails3/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:181:in `const_missing'
/Users/camillavk/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@rails3/gems/cucumber-rails-0.4.1/lib/cucumber/rails/capybara/javascript_emulation.rb:67:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/camillavk/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@rails3/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
/Users/camillavk/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@rails3/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `block in require'
/Users/camillavk/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@rails3/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:227:in `load_dependency'
/Users/camillavk/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@rails3/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
/Users/camillavk/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@rails3/gems/cucumber-rails-0.4.1/lib/cucumber/rails/capybara.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/camillavk/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@rails3/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
/Users/camillavk/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@rails3/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `block in require'
/Users/camillavk/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@rails3/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:227:in `load_dependency'
/Users/camillavk/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@rails3/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
/Users/camillavk/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@rails3/gems/cucumber-rails-0.4.1/lib/cucumber/rails.rb:10:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/camillavk/Documents/Work/Saild/saild/features/support/env.rb:7:in `require'
/Users/camillavk/Documents/Work/Saild/saild/features/support/env.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/camillavk/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@rails3/gems/cucumber-1.1.2/lib/cucumber/rb_support/rb_language.rb:143:in `load'
/Users/camillavk/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@rails3/gems/cucumber-1.1.2/lib/cucumber/rb_support/rb_language.rb:143:in `load_code_file'
/Users/camillavk/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@rails3/gems/cucumber-1.1.2/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:171:in `load_file'
/Users/camillavk/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@rails3/gems/cucumber-1.1.2/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:83:in `block in load_files!'
/Users/camillavk/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@rails3/gems/cucumber-1.1.2/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:82:in `each'
/Users/camillavk/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@rails3/gems/cucumber-1.1.2/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:82:in `load_files!'
/Users/camillavk/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@rails3/gems/cucumber-1.1.2/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:137:in `load_step_definitions'
/Users/camillavk/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@rails3/gems/cucumber-1.1.2/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:39:in `run!'
/Users/camillavk/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@rails3/gems/cucumber-1.1.2/lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:43:in `execute!'
/Users/camillavk/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@rails3/gems/cucumber-1.1.2/lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:20:in `execute'
/Users/camillavk/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@rails3/gems/cucumber-1.1.2/bin/cucumber:14:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/camillavk/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@rails3/bin/cucumber:23:in `load'
/Users/camillavk/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@rails3/bin/cucumber:23:in `<main>'
/Users/camillavk/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@rails3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/Users/camillavk/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@rails3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

Why is Cucumber not able to run anymore? I assume it is because I upgraded Capybara, but I thought cucumber-rails had capybara already in it so I thought this shouldn't affect it?

Here is the relevant parts of my gemfile:

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'test-unit', '1.2.3'
  # gem 'rspec', '1.3.2'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '3.2.0'
end

group :test do
  gem 'capybara', '2.2.0'
  gem 'cucumber', '1.1.2'
  gem 'cucumber-rails', :require => false
  gem 'database_cleaner'
end
```

If it is because of upgrading Capybara, what version of Capybara do I have to downgrade to to have both my Cucumber and Rspec tests able to run?

Comment: what does your env.rb look like? It's complaining about line7

Comment: Line 7 in the env.rb just says: require 'cucumber/rails'

Comment: And it's the first real line of code in your env.rb I guess?

Comment: Yup, before that it's just some comments

Comment: Which version of cucumber and capybara are you currently using? find this by executing `bundle list`, which will show all installed versions in the current bundle

Comment: Cucumber 1.1.2 and Capybara 2.2.0

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried loosening the versions of the gems? There is no need of pinning versions in your gemfile, since gemfile.lock will already ensure the same version is installed everywhere. You should only pin versions if there is a bug or incompatibility issue. Try to state the reason for pinning when doing so.

If you choose to pin the versions, try loosen them on patch level.

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'test-unit', '~> 1.2.3'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.2.0'
end

group :test do
  gem 'capybara', '~> 2.2.0'
  gem 'cucumber', '~> 1.1.2'
  gem 'cucumber-rails', :require => false
  gem 'database_cleaner'
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I didn't know that about pinning versions...but unfortunately it didn't solve my problem...the cucumber tests still say that capybara is not missing constant RackTest

Comment: Have you tried changing the gemfile to these version pins, and running bundle update afterwards? This will upgrade the gems keeping the version contraints (upgrading capybara from 2.2.0 to 2.2.1 instead of fully upgrading to 2.4.4)

Comment: `bundle exec cucumber` or loosing all version pins, and do a full `bundle update`?

Comment: Both didn't work...but it's ok, I'm not desperate for this to work...I don't want to waste time on it as I am just going to upgrade further anyway soon so in the meantime I will just stick to the cucumber tests. Thanks anyway!